# session array won't unset

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have this small script that runs after a user posts.
I have a $_SESSION['con29'][value] that I populate with data from the post.
This code should either add or remove an array element.
It adds an element fine, but I can't work out why it won't unset the $_SESSION array

```
if (isset($_POST['sub_search_content_id']))

    {
        $row_id_1 = $_POST['sub_search_content_id']; 
        $_SESSION['con29'][$row_id_1] = $_POST['sub_search_content_id'];
    }

if (isset($_POST['sub_search_content_id_remove']))

    {
        $ss_id = $_POST['sub_search_content_id_remove'];
        unset($_SESSION['con29'][$ss_id]);
    }
```

Comment: Is this being called inside a function?

Comment: No, this part of the scripts is on the same page as the form.

Comment: @hackenbecker did you start the session? `session_start()`

Comment: Yes the session start is at the top of my page

Answer (score 0):

Use !empty instead isset

because isset only will check variable is created or not 
but !empty will check variable is empty or not too.

and if you don't have another session variables so you may try

`session_unset();`or `session_destroy()`;

and you can also use

> session_register($value);
>
> and
>
> session_unregister($value);

for this

Hope this helps